# Converting IplImage to BufferedImage to integrate

Tags: java, image, image-processing, face-detection

I'm making my own Image processing application that completely operates in BufferedImage.
Now i have stumbled upon a code on Face detection in a blog of [OpenShift.com] 
Now i want to integrate that code into my own GUI application.But facing problems as the Face Detector code the image is an instance of iplImage object and for that i need to first convert the buffered image to IplImage so that the method accepts the now converted image.
Please help..
i am leaving below the Face detector code.

```
public class FaceDetection{

    //Load haar classifier XML file
    public static final String XML_FILE = 
            "C:\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Load image
        IplImage img = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\The Blue Light\\Desktop\\13.jpg");       
        detect(img);        
    }   

    //Detect for face using classifier XML file 
    public static void detect(IplImage src){

        //Define classifier 
        CvHaarClassifierCascade cascade = new CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(XML_FILE));

        CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();

        //Detect objects
        CvSeq sign = cvHaarDetectObjects(
                src,
                cascade,
                storage,
                1.5,
                3,
                CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);

        cvClearMemStorage(storage);


        int total_Faces = sign.total();     

        //Draw rectangles around detected objects
        for(int i = 0; i < total_Faces; i++){
            CvRect r = new CvRect(cvGetSeqElem(sign, i));
            cvRectangle (
                    src,
                    cvPoint(r.x(), r.y()),
                    cvPoint(r.width() + r.x(), r.height() + r.y()),
                    CvScalar.CYAN,
                    2,
                    CV_AA,
                    0);

        }

        //Display result
        cvShowImage("Result", src);
        cvWaitKey(0);

    }           
}
```

Comment: There certainly are many things that may go wrong, but if you already have tried calling `IplImage#getBufferedImage()`, you should describe **what** goes wrong there. Otherwise... try it ;-)

Comment: is IplImage#getBufferedImage() the inbuild method which converts the source IplImage to BufferedImage?

Comment: nope its not working.

Comment: Oh dear! (In a dramatic voice: ) **Then you're dooooommmed!** No seriously, you should describe more clearly **what** you have tried so far, and **in which way** it is "not working". The title says "Converting IplImage to BufferedImage", the text says "Convert the buffered image to IplImage", and you're not mentioning any attempts or error messages. (I'm not sure whether I can help you at all, but you're hardly providing enough information for *anybody* to help...)

Comment: This is the class that loads a jpg file n creates an instance of an object of IplImage and detects faces. (This code works)
Now i want to integrate this code with my GUI but the problem is my gui accepts and works on BufferedImage. 
I need to know for calling the method <detect(IplImage src)> here, that takes in parameters as IplImage, on my gui which works on BufferedImage, so needed to convert my BufferedImage into IplImage first and then pass the Image into this method.

and i have no clue on how to convert it.

Comment: OK, for this direction, you should be able to do `IplImage image = IplImage.createFrom(yourBufferedImage);`

Answer (score 2):

IplImage image = IplImage.createFrom(yourBufferedImage);

Thanks @Marco13 
exactly what i needed..