# Convert IplImage to BufferedImage in javacv

Tags: javacv

I need some help about how to convert IplImage to BufferedImage in java. If someone knows, please answer me. It is better to give some program examples. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting IplImage to BufferedImage to integrate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597104/converting-iplimage-to-bufferedimage-to-integrate)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [link](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/347). It suggests to use `OpenCVFrameConverter.IplImage` with `Java2DFrameConverter`:
http://bytedeco.org/news/2015/04/04/javacv-frame-converters/

Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40195440/1849366).

```
public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(IplImage src) {
  OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage iplConverter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
  Java2DFrameConverter bimConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
  Frame frame = iplConverter.convert(src);
  BufferedImage img = bimConverter. convert(frame);
  BufferedImage result = (BufferedImage)img.getScaledInstance(
      img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), java.awt.Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);  
  img.flush();
  return result;
}
```